# Issue with Datastax Cassandra driver for PHP on CentOS 6.7: undefined symbol: cass_cluster_set_whitelist_dc_filtering in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-php-driver

I have installed the datastax cassandra driver extension for PHP using the following process:

- Installed Dependencies: **automake cmake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool openssl-devel wget gmp gmp-devel boost php-devel pcre-devel git libuv gmp**
- Installed cpp-driver by compiling from the source
- Installed PHP Datastax cassandra driver from the source
- Added extension in the /etc/php.ini file

When I try to execute the php file to connect to the cassandra cluster, I get the following **error**:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/cassandra.so' 
- /usr/lib64/php/modules/cassandra.so: undefined symbol: cass_cluster_set_whitelist_dc_filtering in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried to install again using the binaries instead and I am still facing the same issue.

Here is the ldd output:

```
ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/cassandra.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe9ad9a000)
    libgmp.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3 (0x00007f2377ca2000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f2377a35000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f237781f000)
    libuv.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f23775fe000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f23773f5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f23771d8000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f2376fbf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2376dba000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2376b36000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2376830000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2376619000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2376285000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f2376041000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f2375d59000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f2375b55000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f2375929000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f2375544000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000030d4a00000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f2375339000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f2375135000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2374f1b000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f2374cfb000)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might be using the wrong version of the cpp-driver for the php-driver extension. Currently on php-driver master the cpp-driver submodule is pointing to v2.2.2 whereas the blacklist, whitelist DC, and blacklist DC load balancing policies were added in [v2.3.0](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/releases/tag/2.3.0).

Recommend building and installing the latest release of the cpp-driver and then perform the build and installation steps again for the php-driver source you are utilizing.

Comment: HI Fero,I did removed the old one and installed the new CPP driver **`rpm -qa | grep cassandra-cpp-driver*
cassandra-cpp-driver-devel-2.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
cassandra-cpp-driver-2.3.0-1.el6.x86_64`**
 and rebuild the php driver from the source, but still no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: @Piyush: I performed a fresh installation of CentOS 6.7 [x64] using the DataStax C/C++ driver [v2.3.0](http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/6/v2.3.0/) and libuv [v1.8.0](http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/6/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/) RPM dependencies followed by performing the build process for the DataStax PHP driver [v1.1.0](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/tree/v1.1.0). I have created a Vagrant script [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikefero/a4c76a1dcce6ccae38f5c22bc00f57b2) that you can utilize in order to help you with your build issues.